# Access report loses elements when exported to Word

Tags: vba, microsoft-access

I have created a Microsoft Access Report, with a number of elements in it. These include labels, controls, lines, boxes, etc.

When I export the report to Word, it loses all lines, borders, boxes, etc. Is there a way to keep these elements in an export?

Exporting to PDF is fine, but I need this to work in a Word export.

Answer (score 1):

No. Access only exports to Word in RTF (Rich Text Format). Therefore, it only exports the "text", not the formatting or objects. According to Microsoft:

> When you use the Access Export Wizard to export the data from an
>   Access database to a Word 2010 document, Access creates a copy of the
>   data in a Microsoft Word Rich Text Format file (*.rtf).

[Source](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Export-Access-data-to-a-Word-document-c1e28b16-e0b1-494b-8463-8ca8908a1354)